# live add,edit rows in table with php not works

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I want to create live add and edit row in table.When i click save button, data in text boxes will have to store in database.My code is Below:

```
function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
    var x='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
    var y='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
    var a='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
    var b='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php?type=add",
        data:{x:x,y:y,a:a,b:b},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });  
}
```

add.php

```
if($_GET['type']=="add"){
    $fval=array();
    $fval[0]=$_POST['x'];
    $fval[1]=$_POST['y'];
    $fval[2]=$_POST['a'];   
    $fval[3]=$_POST['b'];       

    $db->connect();
    $rdata=$db->insert('new',$fval,'username,fullname,points,notes');
}
```

But this code is not works.can anyone say, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: use if($_POST['type']=="add")

Comment: still it is not works

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST['type'])` in your `add.php` what is the output ?

Comment: @priyaM give a try on below answer

Comment: I think that `url: "add.php?type=add",` isn't the better way. In HTTP POST Request all parameters are sent in the Request Body, not in the URL. Now you sent `type` as GET and not as POST parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Change your javascript function as below:

```
function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
    var x='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[0] + '">';
    var y='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[1] + '">';
    var a='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[2] + '">';
    var b='<input type="text" class="form-control input-small" value="' + aData[3] + '">';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data:{
            x:x,
            y:y,
            a:a,
            b:b,
            type:'add',
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });  
}
```

And php code as below:

```
if($_POST['type']=="add"){
    $fval=array();
    $fval[0]=$_POST['x'];
    $fval[1]=$_POST['y'];
    $fval[2]=$_POST['a'];   
    $fval[3]=$_POST['b'];       

    $db->connect();
    $rdata=$db->insert('new',$fval,'username,fullname,points,notes');
}
```